# Interval intersection

Tags: java, algorithm, intersection, intervals, interval-intersection

I wrote a class that checks whether two integer intevals overlap.
However I don't like this solution to much. I think that it's possible to do it in a better and simpler way.

```
public class IntegerInterval implements Interval {
private Integer start;
private Integer end;

public IntegerInterval(Integer start, Integer end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}

public Integer getStart() {
    return start;
}

public Integer getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public boolean isOverlapping(IntegerInterval other) {
    if (other != null) {
        return isInInterval(start, other) || isInInterval(end, other)
                || isInInterval(other.start, this) || isInInterval(other.end, this);
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isInInterval(Integer number, IntegerInterval interval) {
    if (number != null && interval != null) {
        if(interval.getStart() == null && interval.getEnd() != null) {
            return number.intValue() <= interval.getEnd().intValue();
        }
        if(interval.getStart() != null && interval.getEnd() == null) {
            return number.intValue() >= interval.getStart().intValue();
        }
        if(interval.getStart() == null && interval.getEnd() == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return interval.getStart() <= number && number <= interval.getEnd();
    }
    else if(number == null && interval != null) {
        return interval.getStart() == null && interval.getEnd() == null;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Interval [0, null] means [0,+infinity], Interval [null,null] means Interval [-infinity, + infinity]. I also have a bunch of unit tests that check, if it's necessary I'll post them too.

Comment: Why not just use `int` instead of `Integer`? Would save you all those null checks, and *if* you ever need a real `Integer` you can just let Java autobox the `int`...

Comment: Because `int` cannot represent infinity.

Comment: Actually this is just simplification of my problem, the real problem is about java.util.Date. I think that I should have mentioned it in the first place.

Comment: You should write what do you mean by "better and simpler". As you see, there could be different views on it. Please, put explaining to your meaning and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should be simpler:

```
public boolean isOverlapping(IntegerInterval other) {
    if (other == null) return false; // for readability's sake, this condition is pulled out

    // overlap happens ONLY when this's end is on the right of other's start
    // AND this's start is on the left of other's end.
    return (((this.end == null) || (other.start == null) || (this.end.intValue() >= other.start.intValue())) &&
        ((this.start == null) || (other.end == null) || (this.start.intValue() <= other.end.intValue())));
}
```

**UPDATE** If compare by `Date` as @Adam actually asked, the code would be:

```
private static boolean dateRangesAreOverlaping(Date start1, Date end1,
                                               Date start2, Date end2) {
return (((end1 == null) || (start2 == null) || end1.after(start2)) &&
         ((start1 == null) || (end2 == null) || start1.before(end2)));
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. I have also simplified my code a little bit. I think that I should mention in the first place that my problem does not concern Integers but Dates (java.util.Date).

Comment: Actually, my overlap algorithm can be generalized to any `Comparable` type including `Date`.

Comment: :) I thought that Integer/Date doesn't matter very much that's why I wrote about integers.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap `start` and `end` in a specific `Comparable` class that is able to encapsulate `null`. This way you only need to invoke `compareTo` in `isInInterval` and don't need to bother with `null`.

That class could also explicitly represent positive and negative infinity.

EDIT:
If you add a type parameter `<T extends Comparable<T>>` to the class declaration and declare the types of `start` and `end` type as `Comparable<T>` then you can use any type that implements `Comparable` with your `Interval`, not only `Integer`.

Comment: Such a simple algorithm needs one more encapsulation? Won't you think that's overkilled? What's wrong with `null` in start as negative infinity and `null` in end as positive infinity?

Comment: @HuiZheng The OP asked how he could make his cleaner. One of the best ways to create clean code is to avoid null checks. The decision if this actually is overkill in his use case should be left to the OP.

Comment: I agree that it's a nice solution, however I think that it's an overkill in this case.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker +1. Obviously, the author of the question means by "better and simpler" something else than we do. ;-)

Comment: Maybe it's just not my level yet ;/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `start < end`. There should be 3 the checks for position of `start` relative to `other`: left, middle and right (right is for completeness as there is no intersection possible). So here are 2 remaining checks:

```
 (start <= other.start && end >= other.start) || 
 (start >= other.start && start <= other.end)  
 // start > other.end means no intersection as end > start > other.end
```

If you do checks for location of `start` as `if` than second chech can be just `(start <= other.end)`:

```
 if (start <= other.start) return end >= other.start;
 else if (start <= other.end) return true;
 else return false;
```

Adjust "=" portions for your needs and add you `null` checks appropriately (i.e. use SpaceTrucker answer to make comaprison with null hidden inside class).

Comment: So you mean that this is the only if that I should write?

Comment: @Adam, I believe it is abaout all checks you need (original actually hade second range slightly off).